# Fatal Python Error: CodecRegistryError due to PYTHONPATH value

Tags: python

Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/**init**.py", line 123
raise CodecRegistryError,
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Current thread 0x00007f01747bf740 (most recent call first):
Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: Could you please provide a bit more information? e.g. What are you trying to do? Where is your minimum reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Default value of PYTHONPATH is given below

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Comment: It looks like you are running Python 2 code in a Python 3 environment. The `raise` statement with a comma is a syntax error in Python 3, and that is what your error message reports.